# Are there more than $\beth_1$ non-homeomorphic topological subspaces of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I've been asked by a younger student about a certain claim he had on a classification of topological subsets of $\Bbb R$. The overall idea was a bit fuzzy, but in hindsight it revolved around taking the $\sigma$-algebra generated by six (Borel) subsets + translations. I successfully (and, I hope, instructively) argumented against it. However, this led me to the question:

> Could I just cut it short and fancy with a cardinality argument? Specifically, if $\sim$ is the homeomorphism equivalence on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, is $\operatorname{card}\left(\mathcal P(\Bbb R)/\sim\right)>\beth_1$ ?

Intuitively, I'd say yes, because, "come on, there are $\beth_2$ nasty non-Borel sets". And, "at chit-chat level, homeomorphisms $(a,b)\to(c,d)$ are monotone functions". However, this is neither a proof nor a sufficient reason for my question to even be decidable in ZFC.

In fact, on the topic I found [this weaker fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602978/how-many-closed-subsets-of-mathbb-r-are-there-up-to-homeomorphism): "closed subsets up to homeomorphism are exactly $\beth_1$".

Thank you for links and/or answers.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly taking the space constructed in the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073427/must-every-subset-of-mathbb-r-contain-2-homeomorphic-distinct-open-sets) and considering all of its subsets should work

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907797/how-many-subspace-topologies-of-mathbbr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable dense subset.  If $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $A\subseteq X$ is a countable dense subset, a homeomorphism from $X$ to another subset $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is determined by its restriction to $A$.  So there is an injection from the set of homeomorphisms from $X$ to other subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to the set of functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$. There are only $\beth_1$ functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ since $A$ is countable.

So each subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be homeomorphic to at most $\beth_1$ other subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Since there are $\beth_2>\beth_1$ different subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, there must be $\beth_2$ different homeomorphism classes of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, in fact that wasn't hard at all! :)

Comment: So, I guess the same goes for any separable topological space with $\beth_1$ elements.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Not quite: you need every subspace to be separable as well (so, for instance, it suffices to assume your space is second-countable).  You also need your space to be Hausdorff, so that a continuous function is determined by what it does on a dense subset.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit of my question