# How many second-countable $T_1$ spaces are there?

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, separation-axioms, second-countable

How many second-countable $T_1$ spaces, up to homeomorphism, are there?

Let $X$ be a second-countable $T_1$ space. Since $X$ is second-countable, there are at most $\beth_1$ open sets in $X$. And since $X$ is $T_1$, every singleton set is closed, so there are at most $\beth_1$ points in $X$.

So *at most*, there are second-countable $T_1$ spaces as many as topologies on spaces with $\beth_1$ points, which are $2^{2^{\beth_1}} = \beth_3$ many. But what's the *exact* cardinality?

Comment: The upper bound can easily be improved to $\beth_2^{\aleph_0}=\beth_2$ since a second-countable topology is determined by giving countably many subsets of the space.  Then the question becomes a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2132119/86856