# Is a set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ homeomorphic to a Vitali set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

A Vitali set is a subset $V$ of the interval $[ 0 , 1 ]$ of real numbers such that, for each real number $r$, there is exactly one number $v ∈ V$ such that $v − r$ is a rational number. It's an example of a set which isn't Lebesgue measurable.

This is a set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$.  But is it homeomorphic to a set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$?  I.e. a subset $W$ of the interval $[ 0 , 1 ]$ of real numbers such that, for each real number $r$, there is exactly one number $v ∈ V$ such that $v − r$ is a dyadic rational.

I have that by a theorem of Sierpinski every countable set with no isolated points is homeomorphic to the others.  So we have a quotient of $\Bbb R$ by two homeomorphic sets.  Does that make the quotients homeomorphic too?

Comment: These Vitali spaces are **topological group quotients**, not just set quotients. And even if they are set quotients, their homotopy types still depend on how these subsets are embedded.

Comment: A set of representatives of each equivalence class (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$) has a very different topology from the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$).  Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Ah good point @EricWofsey I had not picked up on the distinction until you said it. Well the question only makes sense if I say the set of representatives so I have edited the title to reflect that.

Comment: Also, Vitali sets are not all homeomorphic to each other (by the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2132119/86856)).  So conceivably the answer depends on which Vitali set you choose.

Comment: Thanks @EricWofsey it all became a lot clearer once the distinction was made between the set of representatives and the quotient itself.

Comment: @EricWofsey although I guess we have not yet stated here whether there is one set which is homeomorphic to some VItali set.